# writing to disk using xarray to_netcdf is losing the coordinate variables

Tags: python, file, coordinates, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to save a dataset using xarray to_netcdf, but when I write the dataset to disk then read it back in, the coordinates have changed. This is only an occasional problem and I am unable to reproduce it.

EDIT: I have worked out that the problem is to do with the encoding attached to the variable, and can now reproduce the problem with a dummy example:

```
lon = [[-99.83, -99.32], [-99.79, -99.23]]
lat = [[42.25, 42.21], [42.63, 42.59]]
time = pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=3)

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["x", "y", "time"], temperature),),
    coords=dict(
        lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
        lat=(["x", "y"], lat),
        time=time,),
    attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),)


ds.temperature.encoding={'zlib': False,
 'shuffle': False,
 'complevel': 0,
 'fletcher32': False,
 'contiguous': True,
 'chunksizes': None,
 'source': 'fileloc/file.nc',
 'original_shape': (3, 2, 2),
 'coordinates': 'time, lat, lon'}
```

`print(ds)` gives the coordinates as I'd expect, but `ds.to_netcdf('dummy.nc')`, `ds2=xr.open_dataset('dummy.nc')` loses 'lon' as a coordinate and sets it as a data variable.

Does anybody know what in this encoding causes the 'lon' coordinate to shift? I can't see anything relating to 'lon' specifically.

I have updated to the latest version of xarray and tried decode_coords='all' but am still seeing this issue.

Comment: this doesn't happen for me using xarray version `0.20.2`. what version are you using? can you reproduce this with a clean full [mre]?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to recreate the problem as it was only happening sometimes. I think the problem was with the 'encoding' of the dataset. I'll edit the question for clarity and add an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but for something like this we need a reproducible problem. If you’re able to figure out how to create this behavior more consistently I’d suggest filing an issue on github. This isn’t the intended behavior of xarray, so if it really is happening as you describe, it’s a bug.

Comment: If you do continue to see this type of issue, make sure you can create it with a [mre] with the most recent version of xarray. Sometimes upgrading is all you need. But definitely make sure you’re writing to a temporary location so nothing else is affecting the data and make sure your example is the only thing happening in the script.

Comment: Not at all sure, but you might also check if setting the `decode_coords` keyword argument for `xr.open_dataset` to `"all"` helps. `decode_coords` _"Controls which variables are set as coordinate variables"_ according to the [documentation](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html?highlight=open_dataset).